# Hyperbolicity without ergodicity?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, symplectic-geometry, chaos-theory

I have a question concerning the ergodic properties of hyperbolic Hamiltonian flows.

Let $\Phi_{H}^{t}$ be a Hamiltonian flow on a symplectic manifold $\mathcal{M}$. If $\Phi_{H}^{t}$ is Anosov on a compact and connected energy shell $\Sigma_{E}:=\{x\in\mathcal{M}:H(x)=E\}$, is it necessarily ergodic with respect to Liouville measure on $\Sigma_{E}$?

If not, does anyone know of any simple counterexamples? Also, which supplementary assumptions would one need in order to guarantee ergodicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was proved by Anosov that any $C^2$ *transitive* Anosov flow (on a compact manifold) is ergodic (using the Hopf argument). The same can be done for $C^{1+\alpha}$ *transitive* Anosov flows, due to the fact that the stable and unstable foliations remain absolutely continuous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm now a little confused, as I was under the impression that a general smooth Anosov flow need not be ergodic. See here for example: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Xa4xAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA10. There, they say a supplementary assumption of topological transitivity is needed to guarantee ergodicity with respect to a smooth measure (i.e. a measure equivalent to the Riemannian volume). I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: @user78044 I apologize for my rush answer. Indeed I should have written: "transitive Anosov flow" instead of only "Anosov flow". The rest of comment applies (again only to transitive Anosov flows), the reason being that one can show that any ergodic component is open $\bmod0$ and so transitivity gives ergodicity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jonas! Transitivity seems to be a very strong property. I was wondering, do you know of any examples of transitive flows which are not ergodic with respect to a smooth measure? They seem hard to imagine.

Comment: @AlexW I guess if you take any flow you can find a point-dependent rescaling of time (a singular one) such that it stops being ergodic. E.g. if you stay at one point for very long times, your density of SRB measure would have a singularity there.